Not receiving email even if Messaging.SendEmailResult is success
I am sending emails through apex code using Messaging.sendEmail(mailList) in my salesforce applications. It stopped working suddenly few days back. We didn't touch the code.
It seems like some changes in email method Messaging.sendEmail(mailList) which I am missing. I also check the Messaging.SendEmailResult. It is success (Messaging.SendEmailResult[getErrors=();isSuccess=true;]). Not able to find any solution. Posting here to get fews eyes on it.

Check the email deliverability settings are not set to "No Access". This can prevent emails from being sent even if the code is correct.
Check the email limits on your org. Also, check that the email addresses to which you are sending the email are valid.
You can refer to this helpful article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393360&type=1
Also, see these trailhead community threads:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4IR5SAN
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T49tzSAB

